# APC Cache is caching non PHP files

Tags: php, caching, apc

I'm hoping someone can let me know why APC Cache is caching non PHP files? This issue is only happening for one of my sites, the others are not effected.

Here is how I include the footer file :

```
<?php
$basedir = "/www/example.com/httpdocs";
...
...
?>

<div id="footer">
<?php include($basedir . '/include/footer.htm'); ?>
</div>
```

Am I doing something wrong? The APC stat sheet shows the file has been hit 21,000+ times in the 2 days since the cache has been cleared.

Any ideas?